# Chained assignment and circular reference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Consider the following statements:

```
var foo = {n: 1};
foo.bar = foo = {n: 2};
```

Can you explain why `foo.bar` is `undefined` instead of being `foo`?

Comment: the original object `foo` has it, not the new one.

Comment: What if you did `foo.bar = foo = {bar: 2}`? That works.

Comment: @Luminous no it doesn't; `foo.bar === 2`, not `{n: 1}` (`foo`)

Comment: @DanielA.White can you elaborate?

Comment: @Mathletics i added an answer explaining it.

Comment: @Mathletics It gets you a defined answer at least. This question is really out there. `bar` isn't apart of foo. The logic behind why `foo.bar` is undefined is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When executing the assignment operator, JS evaluates the left part first. So this

```
foo.bar = foo = {n: 2};
```

is interpreted as

1. evaluate `foo.bar`. This returns a reference `{base: Object {n:1}, property:bar}`.
2. then evaluate the second assignment:

   2.1 eval `foo`. This returns a reference `{base:<scope>, property:foo}`

   2.2. eval `{n:2}`. This creates a new object.

   2.3 put value: `<scope>.foo = {n:2}`

   2.4 return `{n:2}`
3. put value to the first reference: `{n:1}.bar = {n:2}`. This runs fine, but the old object `{n:1}` is not accessible anymore, since `<scope>.foo` already refers to the new object

Details: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1

If you make a copy of `foo` before, you'll see that the leftmost `=` actually modifies the old object:

```js
var foo = {n:1};
var oldFoo = foo;

foo.bar = foo = {n: 2};

document.write(JSON.stringify(foo) + "<br>")
document.write(JSON.stringify(oldFoo) + "<br>")
```

Answer (score 2):

So by the time the assignment for `foo.bar` happens, the reference is "filled in" for `foo`. which makes it the original object.

Let's expand your code a bit to make it more clear.

```
var foo1, foo2;
foo1 = foo2 = {n:1};
foo1 === foo2; // true
foo1.bar = foo1 = {n:2}
foo1.bar === foo2; // false
foo1 === foo2; // false
```

Comment: and, `foo2.bar === foo1; // true`

Answer (score 1):

There are two objects at play here. One will have a bar property, the other wont. To show this, i'll store the original object in another variable for comparison.

```
var foo = {n: 1};
var orig = foo;
foo.bar = foo = {n: 2};
console.log(foo, orig); // {n:2}, {n:1, bar: {n:2}}
```

Until the `foo.bar` line is done executing, `foo` still contains the original object, so the bar property of the original object will be set to the new object.

Answer (score 0):

You changed the object to which `foo` refers. There is no `bar` in `{n: 2}`. What did you expect?